# Trying to find book about kids who find out there are elves

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find the name of a book about a group of kids who find out there are  elves with powers.

- One with blue skin.
- One who can read minds.
- Another one who was a moto-cross star and couldn't be hurt.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking through the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then editing your question to include any further details you can think to add. The more info you can give us, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you. In particular, it'd be helpful to know in roughly which year or decade you read this, and when you think it might've been published.

Comment: @Toni rollins  Are your descirptions of the appearances and abilities of characters those of the group of kids or those of the group of elves?

Comment: I'm at a loss why this would attract close votes. I can't imagine there are many **novels/with children/find out that elves exist/one with blue skin/one that can read minds/one that rides moto-cross/is invulnerable**

Comment: Certainly I can only think of one @Valorum - motorcycle riding elves are rare.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - Rare indeed; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0uuqW4x3Ps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this could be *[Curse of the Spider King](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?778943)*, the first book of the Berinfell Prophecies series, by Wayne Thomas Batson and Christopher Hopper.

The story concerns seven teenagers. Rather than discovering that "there are elves" though, they actually find that they themselves are elves, and have been kidnapped from the Elven realm and sent to Earth. Each has a particular type of gift or power which reveals itself when they turn thirteen. In particular, two of them are:

> Kat Simonson: A seventh grader in North Hollywood, California; she has
> polycythemia vera, a condition that **gives her skin a bluish color.**
>
> Jett Green: Seventh grader in Greenville, North Carolina. **Rides
> motocross bikes** and plays football.

Jett had a terrible crash on his bike, which should have killed him. However, he recovered the next day with just scratches and bruises, a sign of his physical invulnerability.

In addition Kat is able to hear other's thoughts, a talent she discovered in a history test when she found she could pick up what her classmates were thinking (and thereby obtained a perfect score).

Comment: yes thus is it thank you!!

Comment: @Tonirollins Glad to help! Can you click the checkmark next to your question to accept my answer? Then people will know that the question has been answered. Thanks!